# Is it possible to multithread Curl?

Tags: curl

Please I have a youtube bot written in curl which auto like youtube comments with my accounts, the only problem is that it's not fast as i want. I'm wondering if there's anyway to multithread the comment liking in curl. Cos the accounts login one by one using requests, is there anyway to login simultaneously using curl requests?

Comment: Assuming your code is written in Assembly, yes, you can multi-thread curl, just don't share the same handle in multiple threads. https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html

Comment: Why would it have top be written in assembly for that? libcurl can easily be used multi-threaded.

Comment: Depending on your environment, yes. What are you running curl in?